# How to add an icon before each item in alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using an AlertDialog (see the below code) and would like to put an image before each text.

For example, email icon then text "Email", Facebook icon then text "Facebook", etc.

Using the following code, how to add an icon before each text value?

```
final CharSequence[] items = { "Email", "Facebook", "Twitter", "LinkedIn" };
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(More.this);
builder.setTitle("Share Appliction");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        if (item == 0) {

        } else if (item == 1) {

        } else if (item == 2) {

        } else if(item == 3) {

        }
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792931/how-to-design-single-selection-dialog

Answer (score 92):

You need custom `ListAdapter` to add your image. One way is to subclass the `ArrayAdapter` (used by default by the `AlertDialog`). Here is an example:

```
final Item[] items = {
    new Item("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add),
    new Item("Facebook", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete),
    new Item("...", 0),//no icon for this one
};

ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
    android.R.id.text1,
    items){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Use super class to create the View
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            //Put the image on the TextView
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

            //Add margin between image and text (support various screen densities)
            int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

            return v;
        }
    };


new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Share Appliction")
    .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            //...
        }
    }).show();
```

Here is the Item class

```
public static class Item{
    public final String text;
    public final int icon;
    public Item(String text, Integer icon) {
        this.text = text;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the drawable size ?

Comment: Never mind, just found out how to do it... call setBounds with the required size and then call setCompoundDrawables instead of setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds

Comment: Hi, this works but the size of the text of an item is not the default - it is too big. Any thoughts how I can set it to the default texts size?

Comment: Ok, I managed to get the right size. Instead of `android.R.layout.select_dialog_item` use `typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.AlertDialog_listItemLayout, 0)`. The typed array is defined like that: `TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null, R.styleable.AlertDialog,
                R.attr.alertDialogStyle, 0);` . I took this directly from the support library code for the alert dialog listview.

Comment: Even with `getResourceId` like how @Nedko showed above, it still doesn't render the items like how it looks when using `setItems()`. The item left padding seems to be smaller and makes the items misaligned with title. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hey, Do you mind helping me, why it does not accept tap?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
ViewGroup layout=new LinearLayout(context);
TextView tv=new TextView(context); //your text
tv.setText("my text"); 
ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context); //your icon
//filling image view with icon bitmap (in this case from resource)
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId)));
//ensuring that icon size will be more or less like text height
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setMaxHeight((int )(tv.getLineHeight()*1.5));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
layout.addView(imageView); //adding icon
tv.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT);
layout.addView(tv); //adding text
```

Total idea is to create layout/viewgroup and add icon+text+whatever you want into viewgroup

Comment: how to associate it with alert?

Comment: AlertDialog usually contains ListView which shows messages. So try to get like AlertDialog.getListView(); And then add your layout containing whole stuff with Icon/Text add to listView. like: AlertDialog.getListview().add(layout)

Answer (score 1):

To scale images:

```
//Put the image on the TextView
int dp50 = (int) (50 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R...YOUR_DRAWABLE);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, dp50, dp50, true));
tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null, null, null);

// Add margin between image and text (support various screen densities)
int dp10 = (int) (10 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [Tom Esterez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508194/tom-esterez)'s solution but recommend using the relative function instead for RTL support.

So use this:

```
tv.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].iconID, 0, 0, 0);
```

instead of this:

```
tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].iconID, 0, 0, 0);
```