# How to design Single Selection Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, styling

i want to show dialog like attached Image. an image to the left and text
with single selection.

[image: Share]

any one guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Check my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4697761/508194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to customize the [Context Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) because native context menu doesn't support for icon display inside the dialog, instead it only supports the text to be displayed inside each item.

The image which you have mentioned here is customized context menu with icon. Here is the same example which you want:

1. Source code for the above link: http://code.google.com/p/iconcontextmenu/

Answer (score 2):

To create the dialog like the image is showing, for this you can use [context menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu). And if you want the dialog like that only then let me know.