# How to create custom share dialog in Android

Tags: android, share, android-dialog

I am using share option from my application to social media. Android default share dialog works fine. I want to customize the dialog so that I can rearrange the share dialog UI similarly as in Flipboard android app. Can any one point out how to do that?

Comment: see this example may be helpful for you http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/

Comment: That is a good example. I will try that.

Comment: example is working but you will need to make some changes in it

Comment: like you will need to create an R.layout.basiclistview xml for listview row.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi  are u done custom share dialog

Answer (score 1):

i faced this problem. i found solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697761/6176003) i hope it helps you too..

I write the code of this post below in case of not exist in the future:

You must use a custom ListAdapter to add your image. On way is to subclass the ArrayAdapter (used by default by the AlertDialog). Here is an example:

```
final Item[] items = {
    new Item("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add),
    new Item("Facebook", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete),
    new Item("...", 0),//no icon for this one
};

ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
    android.R.id.text1,
    items){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Use super class to create the View
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            //Put the image on the TextView
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

            //Add margin between image and text (support various screen densities)
            int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

            return v;
        }
    };


new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Share Appliction")
    .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            //...
        }
    }).show();
```

Here is the Item class

```
public static class Item{
    public final String text;
    public final int icon;
    public Item(String text, Integer icon) {
        this.text = text;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```