# Different app name in sharing menu

Tags: android

I'm struggling finding the right keywords to achieve this.

I'm basically trying to have a different app name in the Sharing dialog from other apps, pretty much the same way Pocket shows "Add to Pocket" instead of just "Pocket".

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)
Thanks

Comment: for this u will need to customize Sharing Dialog instead of Default. see [Intercepting Android’s action_send Intents](http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/#) and [How to create custom share dialog in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807490/how-to-create-custom-share-dialog-in-android) for creating custom Sharing dialog where u can easy change sharing app names like "Add to Pocket" instead of just "Pocket"

Comment: Raghav's answer below is doing the same thing more simply and system wide, but thanks for your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the value of `android:label` in the Activity which has the intent filter.

Comment: @Raghav Sood / @Ben Do I need to change the `android:label` within the manifest.xml or in the app itself?

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you

Comment: @Tom : Like this in the manifest                                                                                                         <activity
            android:name=".activity.ProfilePicActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="Set as SwiftMe DP"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">