# Add Image to AlertDialog android with Checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

[Multichoice alertdialog with checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY5Ku.jpg)

i want to add a small icon for each and every option. is there any possibility of doing that without creating a new layout?

something like this.

[Image,Check box and Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6hTf.png)

thanks

Comment: search on google .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954196/alertdialog-with-checkbox-in-android

Comment: i have an alertbox with checkbox. i need to add image for each option..thanks for the replies.

Comment: Check this,http://stackoverflow.com/a/4697761/5515371

Comment: i mean each row having checkbox along with one image right?

Comment: @MujammilAhamed Thanks ill try this.

Comment: @MohitTrivedi yep :)

Comment: Ans it will be in dialog right?

Comment: @MohitTrivedi yah. as an AlertDialog Message.